# --wal-method=stream is not working for Postgresql 10.3

Tags: postgresql-10

I am just leaning streaming replication using postgres Db,
trying to achieve something as described here :- https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres-hot-standby

I have done all the configurations as mentioned for both master and standby server.But in my case I am using Postgres version 10.3.

So while running the pg_basebackup command with option --wal-method=stream I am getting below error:-

```
[vagrant@postgres1 bin]$ ./pg_basebackup -h /tmp/ -p 5432 -D /home/vagrant/postgres/data2  -P -v --wal-method=stream

pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 0/2D000028 on timeline 1
pg_basebackup: starting background WAL receiver
33824/33824 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log end point: 0/2D0000F8
pg_basebackup: waiting for background process to finish streaming ...
pg_basebackup: could not send copy-end packet: no COPY in progress
pg_basebackup: child process exited with error 1
pg_basebackup: removing data directory "/home/vagrant/postgres/data2"
```

But while executing pg_basebackup with --wal-method=fetch option it completed successfully

```
[vagrant@postgres1 bin]$ ./pg_basebackup -h /tmp/ -p 5432 -D /home/vagrant/postgres/data2  -P -v --wal-method=fetch

pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 0/2F000028 on timeline 1
50209/50209 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log end point: 0/2F0000F8
pg_basebackup: base backup completed
```

But what I want is the real time replication of the primary to the secondary, which is possible by `--wal-method=stream` option.

Please let me know if anyone has any inputs for the same.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the value of `max_wal_senders` and `max_replication_slots` on the source database? Do you have any errors in the log file of the source database?

Comment: In the postgresql.conf file of the primary server the value of max_wal_senders = 3 and max_replication_slots =10.

Comment: In the logfile the status is like below:-                                                                                   sending incremental file list
000000010000000000000031

sent 16,781,448 bytes  received 35 bytes  33,562,966.00 bytes/sec
total size is 16,777,216  speedup is 1.00
sending incremental file list
000000010000000000000032
2018-11-30 09:34:55.498 UTC [13343] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2018-11-30 09:34:55.498 UTC [13343] LOG:  unexpected EOF on standby connection

Comment: Now in the logfile its coming as:- 2018-11-30 13:45:50.178 UTC [20025] LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2018-11-30 13:45:50.178 UTC [20025] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: test ! -f /home/vagrant/postgres/archive/00000001000000000000003C && cp pg_wal/00000001000000000000003C /home/vagrant/postgres/archive/00000001000000000000003C

Answer (score 1):

"stream" is the default value for `wal-method`. Just skip this part.

Run the below command without using `--wal-method=stream`

```
./pg_basebackup -h /tmp/ -p 5432 -D /home/vagrant/postgres/data2  -P -v
```